# Splite STring get error Offcet

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to split a string that contains a time like this "23:25:00"

I want to get just hours and minutes but it gives an error like offset ...

I tried this :

```
$time= "12:12:50";
$time = explode(":", $time);
echo $time[0]; // Hours
echo $time[1]; // minutes
```

Comment: where is the `:` in the string ???? `"piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6"`

Comment: voting to close for typo, since the string is just wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = '12:23:59';
$timeParts = explode(':', $time);

echo $timeParts[0] . ': hours';
echo $timeParts[1] . ': minutes';
echo $timeParts[2] . ': seconds';
```